# How to use image upload with reactive forms in Angular 7 with Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

Currently I'm creating a simple CRUD Angular app with Firebase on the backend. It's a simple table with list of students and when it's time to create new student, there appears a popup with name, group, mark and avatar inputs. I use reactive form to handle inputs values. But I can't send to the firebase 64-base string of huge size avatars, because firebase has limit for retrieving string length. I want to upload avatars with huge size, and how should I do it? Thanks. Excuse me for my poor English.

Comment: You should use firebase storage to upload an avatar and save the link of the avatar in the student document.

Comment: @Balaj Khan, thanks for response. You mean that I should send avatar to the firebase as a separate entity, not in the reactive form, but include its link into that form?

Comment: Firebase provide you cloud storage you can follow the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ you can upload your image to cloud storage and get the link of your uploaded image that you can save in your student collection.

Answer (score 0):

You are right firebase does limit the string length! They also limit the size of the document size of database objects. 
The good thing is that firebase provides a service called cloud storage have a look at the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/.
I would recommend that you upload the image to cloud storage using a storage path based on the studentId for example `images/students/<studentId>`. This way if you need to delete a user, before deleting the user you can go to cloud storage and delete the avatar image linked with student. Also it's a good idea if you want to upload a new image to replace the old image you can do so easily.
Also a good path storage side system like this makes it a lot easier for you to get the downlaodURL on the client side based on the studentID.